# Capturing a parameter with a Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

What code is generated by the C# compiler when I try to capture the parameter of a function?

```
partial class NewClass : Window
{
    public NewClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(Work).Start();
    }

    void Work()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate time-consuming task
        UpdateMessage("The answer");
    }

    void UpdateMessage(string message)
    {
        Action action = () => txtMessage.Text = message;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
}
```

I know lambdas can hold variables in their lexical scope after a new class is created - where said variables are stored as fields.  The fields replace any original occurrence of captured ones. But in this case, since no original value is being replaced, will a value be created from scratch? What's the magic behind this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So if I've got this right, there's nothing wrong with its behavior, you just want to see the IL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what's going on here is that you're not actually closing over `txtMessage`, technically.  What you're doing is closing over `this`.

Every instance method has an implicit first parameter of the type of the class itself, called `this`.  The access of any instance members assumes that they are accessing members of that implicitly defined `this` variable.

Once you make all of that implicit code explicit, it becomes just another closure over any other locally scoped variable.

So first we make `this` explicit: (This isn't technically valid C#, it is merely for demonstrative purposes and is designed to be a representation of the semantic representation of the code by the C# compiler.)

```
void UpdateMessage(NewClass this, string message)
{
    Action action = () => this.txtMessage.Text = message;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

Then we do the traditional closure transformations of a locally scoped variable on that:

```
class ClosureClass1
{
    public string message;
    public NewClass @this;
    public void AnonymousMethod1()
    {
        @this.txtMessage.Text = message;
    }
}

void UpdateMessage(NewClass this, string message)
{
    ClosureClass1 closure = new ClosureClass1();
    closure.@this = this;
    closure.message = message;
    Action action = closure.AnonymousMethod1;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The NewClass contains a created private field of type <>c__DisplayClass1 class which contains a public string field 'message'. Each time the UpdateMessage is called the method instantiates a new instance of the <>c__DisplayClass1 class and assigns the message passed into the UpdateMessage method (by value). It also contains the < UpdateMessage >b__0 which is the action to execute (assign textbox with the message value). The textbox value is set by using the 'this' field which is the MainWindow class.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this answers your question!